# How can I convert dynamic row data to XML in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some data in a table that looks like this.

```
ID     KEY       VAL
----   -----    -----
1      name     Bob
1      age      30
1      gender   male
2      name     Susan
2      age      50
```

It possible to get the output of this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id = 1;
```

..in a XML format like this:

```
<DATA>
  <NAME>Bob</NAME>
  <AGE>30></AGE>
  <GENDER>MALE</MALE>
</DATA>
```

I've had to resort to PL/SQL as I haven't been able to build up the tag names dynamically using SQL? Is this possible using the SQL methods Oracle 11g or I have to continue the PL/SQL way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select xmlelement("DATA",xmlagg( xmlelement(evalname(KEY), VAL)))
from my_table
where ID = 1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d00e9/4)

Comment: Me neither. It is interesting that `XMLELEMENT`, when given a column name for the first parameter, interprets it a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with pure SQL:

```
select XMLELEMENT("DATA",
         XMLELEMENT("NAME", n.val), 
         XMLELEMENT("AGE", a.val), 
         XMLELEMENT("GENDER", g.val))
from my_table n
inner join my_table a on n.id = a.id
inner join my_table g on n.id = g.id
where n.key = "name" 
and   a.key = "age"
and   g.key = "gender"
and   n.id  = 1;
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for me as I don't know the name of the keys. It would have to be dynamic. I'm sorry I wasn't more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
    SELECT xmlelement("Data",xmlelement("Name",name),
xmlelement("Age",age),
xmlelement("Gender",gender)) "xml_format"
      FROM emp_tab  where rownum=1;
```

any clarification plz let me know!